# Removing outliers and surrounding data from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data set containing some outliers that I'd like to remove.
I want to remove the 0 value in the data frame shown below:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'Time': [0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9], 'data': [1.1, 1.05, 1.01, 1.05, 0, 1.2, 1.1, 1.08, 1.07, 1.1]})
```

I can do something like this in order to remove values below a certain threshold:

```py
df.loc[df['data'] < 0.5, 'data'] = np.NaN
```

This yelds me a list without the '0' value:

```py
   Time  data
0   0.0  1.10
1   0.1  1.05
2   0.2  1.01
3   0.3  1.05
4   0.4   NaN
5   0.5  1.20
6   0.6  1.10
7   0.7  1.08
8   0.8  1.07
9   0.9  1.10
```

However, I am also suspicious about data surrounding invalid values, and would like to remove values '0.2' units of Time away from the outliers. Like the following:

```py
   Time  data
0   0.0  1.10
1   0.1  1.05
2   0.2   NaN
3   0.3   NaN
4   0.4   NaN
5   0.5   NaN
6   0.6   NaN
7   0.7  1.08
8   0.8  1.07
9   0.9  1.10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a list of all points in time in which you have bad measurements and filter for all nearby time values:

```py
bad_times = df.Time[df['data'] < 0.5]

for t in bad_times:
    df.loc[(df['Time'] - t).abs() <= 0.2, 'data'] = np.NaN
```

result:

```
>>> print(df)
   Time  data
0   0.0  1.10
1   0.1  1.05
2   0.2   NaN
3   0.3   NaN
4   0.4   NaN
5   0.5   NaN
6   0.6   NaN
7   0.7  1.08
8   0.8  1.07
9   0.9  1.10
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get a list of Time to be deleted, and then apply nan for those rows.

```
df.loc[df['data'] < 0.5, 'data'] = np.NaN
l=df[df['data'].isna()]['Time'].values
l2=[]
for i in l:
    l2=l2+[round(i-0.1,1),round(i-0.2,1),round(i+0.1,1),round(i+0.2,1)]
df.loc[df['Time'].isin(l2), 'data'] = np.nan
```